# Weird behavior UIView animation on gesture recognizer's sender.view in paging UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation, uipinchgesturerecognizer

**Setup:**

I have a horizontal paging `UIScrollView` set up with help of the `LXPagingViews` class (to easily add a 'peeping' `UIScrollView`). This is set up, so you can flick between different views in the `UIScrollView`. I have added a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to every view, so when the user pinches on a view, it displays a 'zooming' animation, and segues into a detail view. A screenshot for more clarity:

[image: My paging UIScrollView]

**Problem:**

When I pinch one of the views, the zoom animation starts and the view segues into the detail view. This works fine, EXCEPT for the last view in the `UIScrollView`. In the last view (doesn't matter how many views it has, as long as it has more than 2), when the animation plays, it spawns a new view behind the view I tapped, and animates that one. This makes for a weird animation. Also, the view doesn't get blocked from input by the animation, because it spawns a new one. This means that the user can spawn multiple views quickly by pinching fast.

I hope this screenshot illustrates the problem a bit:

[image: When the user pinches, a new view spawns behind and animates]

**What I have tried:**

- Debugging the gesture recognizer's superview subviews, to see if more views spawn
- Monitoring what view get's animated. For every pinch the user does, another view gets animated for some reason
- Tried to use another way of setting the image instead of lazy-loading. Didn't help
- Tried other images, more and less views, orientation differences and empty views.

**Code:**

Adding the gesture recognizer to the view:

```
- (UIView<ReusableView> *)pagingView:(PagingView *)thePagingView reusableViewForPageIndex:(NSUInteger)thePageIndex withFrame:(CGRect)theFrame {
    // View's Identifier
    static NSString *theIdentifier = @"voucherDetailView";
    VoucherDetailView *thePageView = (VoucherDetailView *)[thePagingView dequeueReusableViewWithIdentifier:theIdentifier];
    if (thePageView == nil) {
        thePageView = [[VoucherDetailView alloc] initWithFrame:theFrame];
    } else {
        thePageView.frame = theFrame;
    }

    Voucher *voucher = [_vouchers objectAtIndex:thePageIndex];
    NSURL *fullVoucherImageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:voucher.fullVoucherImage];
    [thePageView.voucher setImageWithURL:fullVoucherImageUrl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"11283253-nederland_kaart"]];

    // Gesture recognizer    
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openZoomablePinch:)];
    [thePageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

    return thePageView;
}
```

The pinch handler:

```
- (void)openZoomablePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    // Only allow one pinch to activate the animation
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // Bring the view to the front so it doesn't clip with the peeping views
        [sender.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:sender.view];
        CGAffineTransform trans = sender.view.transform;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             sender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sender.view.transform, 1.15, 1.15);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             if (finished && self.view.window) {
                                 sender.view.transform = trans;
                                 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"voucherZoomSegue" sender:self];
                             }
                         }];
    }
}
```

**EDIT: PagingView code that gets called on the last view when pinching:**

```
    UIView<ReusableView> *theRightMostReusableView = [self.visibleReusableViews lastObject];
    NSUInteger theRightMostPageIndex = (NSUInteger)floorf(CGRectGetMinX(theRightMostReusableView.frame) / thePageWidth);
    while ((theRightMostPageIndex != MAX(0, self.numberOfItems - 1)) && (theRightMostPageIndex < theToIndex)) {
        theRightMostPageIndex = MIN(theRightMostPageIndex + 1, MAX(0, self.numberOfItems - 1));
        CGFloat theMinX = theRightMostPageIndex * thePageWidth;
        CGRect theRect = CGRectMake(theMinX, 0.0f, thePageWidth, thePageHeight);
        UIView<ReusableView> *theReusableView = [self.dataSource pagingView:self reusableViewForPageIndex:theRightMostPageIndex withFrame:theRect];
        if (!CGRectContainsRect(theRect, theReusableView.frame)) {
            @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                                           reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                   @"theReusableView's frame (%@) must be contained by the given frame (%@)",
                                                   NSStringFromCGRect(theReusableView.frame),
                                                   NSStringFromCGRect(theRect)]
                                         userInfo:nil];
        }
        [self.visibleReusableViews addObject:theReusableView];
        [self addSubview:theReusableView];
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have uploaded a small demo project [here](http://speedy.sh/dCc34/Stackoverflow-demo-project.zip). The way to use it, set the simulator (or your device) in landscape, go to Peeping Paging View, and try to pinch/tap the views (except the first one). As you can see, the views get zoomed, except for the last view, which spawns a new view behind it and zooms that one (the '9' stays the same size).

The code is in the `PeepingPagingViewController.m`.

**Solution (thanks to Oladya Kane):**

The rightmost visible index is mistakingly indexed as the leftmost visible index. The code I had to change was the line:

```
NSUInteger theRightMostPageIndex = (NSUInteger)floorf(CGRectGetMinX(theRightMostReusableView.frame) / thePageWidth);
```

to

```
NSUInteger theRightMostPageIndex = MIN((NSInteger)floorf((CGRectGetMaxX(theRightMostReusableView.frame) - 0.1f) / thePageWidth), MAX(0, self.numberOfItems - 1));
```

Comment: Did you check if the `reusableViewForPageIndex` is called when you pinch the last view ? If yes, there is a problem with the gesture on your ScrollView class.

Comment: Good point! It indeed gets called when I pinch the last view, and doesn't get called for the others. Do you have any idea where I should look in the ScrollView class? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Check where the `reusableViewForPageIndex` is called in the custom view controller and see for which condition this method is called, some condition is wrong and that's why it's creating another view. Also make sure that the `dataSource` is correct (doesn't have more views than it should)

Comment: The dataSource is correct. It has exactly the amount of views that are needed. I am using the '[LXPagingViews](https://github.com/lxcid/LXPagingViews)' library for the peeping paging views. I have isolated the piece of code that calls `reusableViewForPageIndex` and edited my question. To be honest though, I do not see anything wrong with the code, but it can be that I have tunnel vision on this code :P. Do you see anything wrong with it? Thanks again for assisting me.

Comment: I see that you make addSubview: but not removeFromSuperview , are you sure you aren't adding view above view?

Comment: Yeah this added piece of code is used in the layout of the Paging `UIScrollView`'s subviews. This piece specifically is used to layout the most right subview of the current visible views. The problem is not how the view gets layout, but the fact that it even gets called in the first place (by me pinching the view and activating the animation).

Comment: Can you give the project so I can analyze it and see what i can come up with?

Comment: Yeah I have made a small demo project which illustrates the bug. I have added the project to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked through you demo code and found following bug:

When your pinch gesture recognizer is called, you animate it's sender frame. This forces `PageView` to layout its subviews -> it calls your delegate method

```
- (UIView<ReusableView> *)pagingView:(PagingView *)thePagingView reusableViewForPageIndex:(NSUInteger)thePageIndex withFrame:(CGRect)theFrame
```

Here you provide view to `PagingView` and it adds your view beneath your last view, messing up your view hierarchy. I think you might use some kind of a flag somewhere to prevent PagingView from requesting new views. The strangest thing is that this kind of behavior happens only for last view.
Hope this will help you.

**EDIT:**

I found the problem.
In the method

```
- (void)layoutSubviewsFromIndex:(NSUInteger)theFromIndex toIndex:(NSUInteger)theToIndex
```

indexes of the leftmost and rightmost visible views are computed. But the rightmost visible index is mistakenly computed as the leftmost index, so, you need to replace this line:

```
NSUInteger theRightMostPageIndex = (NSUInteger)floorf(CGRectGetMinX(theRightMostReusableView.frame) / thePageWidth);
```

With this one:

```
NSUInteger theRightMostPageIndex = MIN((NSInteger)floorf((CGRectGetMaxX(theRightMostReusableView.frame) - 0.1f) / thePageWidth), MAX(0, self.numberOfItems - 1));
```

This will prevent PagingView from requesting new views for already visible last (rightmost) view.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question and demo project. I will try your suggestion of preventing the calling of the `reusableViewForPageIndex` method and report back here. It is indeed weird that this only happens for the last view.

Comment: I fixed the problem. By adding a boolean property `isLastView` to the PagingView's delegate. I have posted the code in my question. Still doesn't explain why it only happens for the last view (weird behavior). If you could answer that, I will reward the bounty.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks alot! I guess I looked over that line too easily. I will award the bounty (in 1hour I can do so).